# Is there a method to pivot an array of 2 key value pairs to a single key value?

Tags: php, arrays

When pulling information from a table, you can usually get :

```
Field1  |  Field2
=================
ValueX  |  ValueY
ValueA  |  ValueB
```

Which when retrieved, ends up as :

```
array(
    array(
           "Field1"=>"ValueX",
           "Field2"=>"ValueY"
    ),
    array(
           "Field1"=>"ValueA",
           "Field2"=>"ValueB"
    )
)
```

What I would like to do, is flip the array around so it becomes this:

```
array(
     "ValueX"=>"ValueY",
     "ValueA"=>"ValueB"
)
```

Is there any built in way to do this in PHP, and If not, what would be the most resource friendly approach to getting this done ?

Comment: By this  `"ValueX"=>"ValueB"` Do you mean this  `"ValueA"=>"ValueB"` ?

Comment: @AmrBerag - yes.  I have edited the question with the correction.  Thank you for noticing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's a typo in your expected output(ValueX for both results), but using `array_column` can convert the array to be how you want it...

```
$array1 = array(
    array(
        "Field1"=>"ValueX",
        "Field2"=>"ValueY"
    ),
    array(
        "Field1"=>"ValueA",
        "Field2"=>"ValueB"
    )
);

$array2 = array_column($array1, "Field2", "Field1");
print_r($array2);
```

gives...

```
Array

(
    [ValueX] => ValueY
    [ValueA] => ValueB
)
```

Comment: Yes, that was what I am looking for. :)   Thank you.  (it was a typo, and I updated after it was pointed out)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get your array without using keys (columns names):

```
$result=array();
foreach ($array as $subarr){
  $arr = array_values($subarr);
  $result[$arr[0]] = $arr[1];
}
var_dump($result);
```

outputs:

```
array(2) { ["ValueX"]=> string(6) "ValueY" ["ValueA"]=> string(6) "ValueB" }
```

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this without "foreach" "while", etc.